# Regularity of the Minkowski functionnal of a convex

Tags: convexity, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a convex compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $0 \in \overset{\circ}{K}$. The Minkowski functional associated to K is: 
\begin{align*}
\varphi_K(x):= \inf \left\{t>0 \; : \;  tx \in K \right\}
\end{align*}

Is there some results linking the regularity of $\varphi_K$ to the regularity of $\partial K$?
For example, if $\partial K$ is $C^2$, can I expect $\varphi_K$ to be $C^2$? I would gladely look into any reference.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.